Random variable in its CDF
Let $X$ be a random variable with its corresponding CDF $F_{X}$ and $Y=F_X(X)$. Can we, hence, say that $Y = F_X(X) = \mathbb{P}(X \le X) = 1$, because $X$ is always not greater than itself ? I was told that the solution is flawed, but I cannot see why.
Could someone help me get this? Thank you in advance.

$F_X(x)=P(X\le x)$ does not hold when $x$ is replaced by a random variable.

@geetha290krm Could you please explain in detail why it does not hold? What exactly is breaking here?

$\mathsf P(X\leq x)$ does not depend on what value random variable $X$ has at any moment.
It is not the indicator that $X\leq x$ occurs, which would have binary values: $$\mathbf 1_{X\leq x}=\begin{cases}1&:& X\leq x\\0&:& X>x\end{cases}$$
Rather is the prior probability that $X\leq x$ would occur.
Thus: $F_X(X)$ is a random variable expressing the probability that $X$ would have had at most the value that it actually does.
$$F_X(X)=\left.\mathsf P(X\leq x)\right\vert_{x=X}$$

Examples:

If $X\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$, then $Y=X$ .

If $X\sim\mathcal{Geo_0}(p)$, then $Y=1-(1-p)^{\lfloor X+1\rfloor}$.



Alternatively:
Let $X$ and $S$ be independent and identically distributed.
This entails that $\mathsf P(X\leq x) = \mathsf P(S\leq x)$ for all values for $x$.
Meaning that so too will $F_X(x)=F_S(x)$.
And thus we would prefer that $F_X(X)=F_S(X)$ also holds.
But as $\mathsf P(X\leq X)\neq \mathsf P(S\leq X)$, we therefore do not equate $F_X(X)$ either with $\mathsf P(X\leq X)$ nor with $\mathsf P(S\leq X)$.
Rather we use $F_X(X)=\mathsf P(X\leq x)\vert_{x:=X}$ ; the result of the function with the argument $x$ replaced with random variable $X$ after it is evaluated.
